# How to calculate a duration between two dates in luxon?

Tags: javascript, luxon

Luxon's [documentation for the `Duration.fromISO` method](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/duration.js%7EDuration.html#static-method-fromISO) describes it as

> Create a Duration from an ISO 8601 duration string

Nowhere is mentioned the ability to create a duration **based on two dates**. My typical use case would be: *"did the event between date ISODAT1 and ISODATE2 last more than an hour?"*.

What I will do is to transform the dates into a timestamp and check whether the difference is greater than 3600 (seconds), I believe however that there is a more native way to make the check.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could use `DateTime`'s `.diff` ([doc](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math?id=diffs))

> Return the difference between two DateTimes as a Duration.

```js
const date1 = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("2020-09-06T12:00")
const date2 = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("2019-06-10T14:00")

const diff = date1.diff(date2, ["years", "months", "days", "hours"])

console.log(diff.toObject())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Documentation linked in this answer seems to have moved to https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math?id=diffs

Comment: @AnibeAgamah thank you, I've just updated the link

Comment: This is the doc link of the API, also useful: https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimediff

Answer (score 19):

### Example

```js
const date1 = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("2020-09-06T12:00");
const date2 = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("2019-06-10T14:00");
const diff = Interval.fromDateTimes(later, now);
const diffHours = diff.length('hours');

if (diffHours > 1) {
  // ...
}
```

### Documentation for Luxon v2.x

In the Luxon documentation they mention durations and intervals.
It seems that you would be best off using Intervals and then calling the `.length('hours')` on the Interval if you're interested to know if something has been over an hour.

- https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/tour?id=durations
- https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/tour?id=intervals

#### Durations

> The Duration class represents a quantity of time such as "2 hours and 7 minutes".

```js
const dur = Duration.fromObject({ hours: 2, minutes: 7 });

dur.hours;   //=> 2
dur.minutes; //=> 7
dur.seconds; //=> 0

dur.as('seconds'); //=> 7620
dur.toObject();    //=> { hours: 2, minutes: 7 }
dur.toISO();       //=> 'PT2H7M'
```

#### Intervals

> Intervals are a specific period of time, such as "between now and midnight". They're really a wrapper for two DateTimes that form its endpoints.

```js
const now = DateTime.now();
const later = DateTime.local(2020, 10, 12);
const i = Interval.fromDateTimes(now, later);

i.length()                             //=> 97098768468
i.length('years')                      //=> 3.0762420239726027
i.contains(DateTime.local(2019))       //=> true

i.toISO()       //=> '2017-09-14T04:07:11.532-04:00/2020-10-12T00:00:00.000-04:00'
i.toString()    //=> '[2017-09-14T04:07:11.532-04:00 – 2020-10-12T00:00:00.000-04:00)
```

Comment: The irony is that  on the project that got me looking into this my teammate ended up recommending we go with something like: `DateTime.now().diff(DateTime.fromISO(date))`

Comment: In this example, what if I wanted only - if 2 hours or less? .ie. "Difference cannot be more than 2 hours"

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I would imagine you could subtract the two dates and instantiate a duration from it, thus grabbing the hours and checking it out. Otherwise given the example above you could take two dates, and use the `Interval.fromDateTimes(date1, date2).length('hours')` I believe.

Comment: Thanks @CTS_AE - I did this instead which works as expected.

`if (durToObject.hours >= 2 && durToObject.minutes >= 1) { **Error** }`

Answer (score 1):

We can also convert to duration and find what OP asked `did the event between date ISODAT1 and ISODATE2 last more than an hour?`

```
// Get the hour duration between two dates
const hoursBetween = Interval.fromDateTimes(date1, date2).toDuration('hours').hours;

// Or simply check it
if(Interval.fromDateTimes(date1, date2).toDuration('hours').hours > 1) {
  // yes, it did last more than an hour
}
```

Luxon Doc: [Luxon intervaltoduration](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#intervaltoduration)